# Cannot ssh over pptp after upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ssh, vpn

After i upgraded to ubuntu 15.10 i cannot establish ssh connection to my server over pptp but i can ssh from my server to the upgraded pc. In local network ssh works fine. Also my nfs mounts hangs after some time which are also over pptp mounted. I can connect with samba, ftp to my server, i have ping to the server.
This is output when i try ssh over pptp:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_configdebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.88.100 [192.168.88.100] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/rpr/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/rpr/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/rpr/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/rpr/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/rpr/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/rpr/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/rpr/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/rpr/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2_hpn13v11 FreeBSD-20130515
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2_hpn13v11 FreeBSD-20130515 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.88.100:22 as 'rpr'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
```

Comment: You may have to redo the PPTP configuration.  However, note that PPTP is *old and insecure*, and you should consider using OpenVPN or IPSec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try lowering the mtu down to something like 1392.  You can test this by typing:

```
ifconfig ppp0 mtu 1392
```

or another value below 1492
once you find a value that works then to make it permanent edit the /etc/ppp/peers/ and add

```
mtu <value>
```

eg. mtu 1492